# Como implementar o método DELETE do protocolo HTTP em um Web Service REST em Java

Tags: java, web-service, rest

estou com dúvida de como poderia implementar o método DELETE do protocolo HTTP web service REST JAVA, quando executo ele diz que estou executando o método GET e nao DELETE.

//Método chamado no Web Service

```
 public void remove(Promocao promocao) {

        id_conexao = N.Conectar();

        String sql = "delete from promocao where idpromocao=?";

        try {

            stmt = id_conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, promocao.getIdpromocao());

            //executa
            stmt.execute();

            System.out.println("Promocao Excluida");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("ERRO ao excluir promoção - " + e);

        } finally {
            N.Desconectar();
        }
    }
```

//DELETE no Web Service Java

```
    @DELETE
    @Path("excluirPromocao")
     public void excluir(String content){    

      Gson g = new Gson();
        Promocao P = (Promocao) g.fromJson(content, Promocao.class);
        PromocaoOp promo = new PromocaoOp();  
        promo.remove(P);

    }
```

Comment: Você usa algum framework? Sabe tratar `GET` e `POST` separadamente?

Comment: Criei um Web Service Java utilizando o netBeans basicamente ele faz uma conexão ao MYSQL e chama o método para excluir vou postar o que fiz